# Why does this for loop produce numbers, when I am writing strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have one question about this `for` loop, that writes strings to a file:

```
>>> n=15
>>> for i in range (n):
...    outfile.write(str(i)+' '+str(i*i)+'\n')
...
4
4  
4
4
5 
5
5
5
5
5
7
7
7
7
7
```

Why am I getting those numbers?

Comment: That is just the representation in the console. If you store the value to a variable and check its type, you will see that it is indeed a string.

Answer (score 2):

In the interactive interpreter mode, Python will echo all expression statement results that are not `None`.

Here, the number are the return values of all the `outfile.write(...)` calls. Assuming `outfile` is a file openened in text mode, the [`file.write()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.write) returns the number of characters written.

For example, the first line written is `'0 0\n'`, which is 4 characters, as are `'1 1\n'`, `'2 4\n'` and `'3 9\n'`, after which you write 5 characters for `'4 16\n'`, etc.

If you don't want to see those numbers, assign the return value of the `.write()` method to a variable. It doesn't matter what variable here; an assignment statement is not an expression statement so there is nothing to echo:

```
>>> for i in range (n):
...    written = outfile.write(str(i)+' '+str(i*i)+'\n')
...
>>>
```